# Unbundeling a pre-built Javascript file built using browserify

Tags: browserify, browserify-shim

I have a third party library,  non uglified which was bundled using browserify.  Unfortunately the original sources are not available.

Is there a way to unbundled it into different files/sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to 'unbundle' the pre-built Browserify bundle using [browser-unpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-unpack).

It will generate JSON output like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "source": "\"use strict\";\r\nvar TodoActions = require(\"./todo\"); ... var VisibilityFilterActions = require(\"./visibility-filter\"); ...",
    "deps": {
      "./todo": 2,
      "./visibility-filter": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "source": "\"use strict\";\r\n ...",
    "deps": {}
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "source": "\"use strict\";\r\n ...",
    "deps": {}
  },
  ...
]
```

It should be reasonably straight-forward to transform the JSON output into source files that can be required. Note that the mappings of `require` literals (like `"./todo"`) are in the `deps`. That is, the module required as `"./todo"` corresponds to the source with an `id` of `2`.

There is also a [browserify-unpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-unpack) tool - which writes the contents as files - but I've not used it.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like  a charm.